# Should I return -1 or int? or use out parameter to return result of a database action?

Tags: c#, null, return-value, value-type

I'm writing public functions in one project for some database actions meant to be called from other projects. Straight to code, I can go for following approaches:

```
public int GetCount(Apple apple, Orange orange)
{
    try 
    { 
       // query; 

       return 1000;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // log it
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

or

```
public int? GetCount(Apple apple, Orange orange)
{
    try 
    { 
       // query; 

       return 1000;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // log it
        return null; 
    }
}
```

or

```
public bool GetCount(Apple apple, Orange orange, out int count)
{
    count = -1;
    try 
    { 
       // query; 

       count = 1000;
       return true;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // log it
        return false; 
    }
}
```

I currently do the "null" way for other business objects, like:

```
public Apple GetApple(Orange orange)
{
    try 
    { 
       // query; 

       return apple;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // log it
        return null; 
    }
}
```

And the caller checks if the value returned is `null` and accordingly pops an error message. **So I'm inclined to use `int?` as return type for value types as well. But I would love to know what is an acceptable design or encouraged practice for these things..**

**Edit:** If I put try catch around the caller, wouldn't that leave my code base littered with try catch everywhere? Isn't it easier to catch exception from the callee so that **all the functions that call it need not care? What is wrong if callee catches the error and lets the caller know some error had happened?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, It's quite subjective and you won't get standardized answers, but [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) book, which is good resource for developing conventions, states "Do not swallow error by catching non-specific exceptions, such as `Exception` or `SystemException`". If you swallow it and return some magic value including `null`, you won't be able to recognize the underlying reasons for system failure.

Personally, I would go with

```
public int GetCount(Apple apple, Orange orange)
{
    try 
    { 
       return // query; 
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // log it
        throw;
    }
}
```

Another personal point - I've spend too much time diagnosing and debugging in order to understand **why** system is not working and then, in the end, just to find out that exception was silently logged and swallowed. Now I'm felling so much pain, when I encounter code like `catch(Exception e) { return null; }`.

Comment: But doesnt that mean one have to write try catch again from the caller side to know of the error?

Comment: First, one big point - why are you trying to write `catch` block, if ou can't handle the exception? You know, that Java team named it wrong - it's not `catch`, it's `handle` *(not trying to be insulting)*. Catching the exception and not throwing it back is almost always useless

Comment: So are you not saying there needs to be no try catch at all at the callee (the `GetCount` method)? But you have used one in your answer.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Actually, there are many cases where finding out that an exception occurred is useful; what's missing in Java, C#, and VB.net, and can only accurately be simulated in the latter, is a means by which code in a `finally` block can find out what exception (if any) is pending without pretending to handle it.

Answer (score 4):

It is bad practice to swallow exceptions.

If the exception cannot be handled by the method, bubble it up to the caller:

```
public int GetCount(Apple apple, Orange orange)
{
    try 
    { 
       // query; 

       return 1000;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // log it
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesnt that mean one have to write try catch again from the caller side to know of the error?

Comment: hmm wouldnt that leave my code base littered with try catch everywhere. I had thought its easier to catch exception from the callee so that all the functions that call it doesnt need to care. What is wrong if callee catches it and lets the caller know some error had happened?

Comment: `and lets the caller know some error had happened` yes, and this is done via exceptions. What's the point of the callee catching it?

Comment: Checking some return value litters the code as well. The way to let the caller know some error had happened is to throw an exception. As *Ilya Ivanov* writes, swallowing the exception can lead to very difficult to debug bugs.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov The point I had seen was that writing try catch again from the caller side will litter my code all over with try catches. With my approach I need to write it in one place, and not the 100 places where it will be called. But dtb has an interesting point.

Comment: @dtb if the way to let the caller know some error had happened is to throw an exception, then why have try catch at all in the callee? We just need to have it around caller right? Even in that case the error from callee bubbles to caller right? Or should I make it another question?

Comment: For logging, you can catch the exception in your `GetCount` method, log it and re-throw it. That way the callers don't have to care about logging, just about showing the error message.

Comment: @dtb thanks, interesting. So you're saying try catches in callee are merely for logging. I can very well get the callee information from the caller too for the purpose of logging (i mean can log from caller too), from stack trace. I have decided to completely take off logging and try catch from callee!! :)

Comment: @dtb Can you edit your answer to incorporate the relevant portions in your comments (on why it whats wrong with callee catching) so that I can mark yours as answer? Right now Illyas answer looks better

Answer (score 1):

In situations where `int` provides a value which is clearly not otherwise legitimate for the domain, and where there's no need for `default<int>` to be anything other than zero, I don't see any advantage to `Nullable<T>`.  The `Nullable<int>` types are annoying for callers to work with, since it's necessary to test for null and then extract the value to some other storage location before use.  If one makes the mistake of doing something like:

```
if (res.HasValue)
  for (i=0; i<res.Value; i++)
    ....
```

then loop overhead will likely be more than double what it would have been with:

```
if (res.HasValue)
{
  int resValue = res.Value;
  for (i=0; i<resValue; i++)
    ....
}
```

but requiring the caller to create an extra variable to avoid an absurd level of loop overhead seems burdensome.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `int?` as well. It is important to note that, this helps you in using all the numbers - and not reserving a particular number to identify a status.

This is what `C` and `C++` lack, which use integers to convey status, inadvertently reserving a number for special use.